# How to customise multiple blog widgets in a single page

Tags: orchardcms

I am fairly new to Orchard, really impressed with what I have seen so far.

My question:

I have a site that uses blogs fairly heavily as content. On the homepage, there are the following widgets:
'featured' - a blog post that has a featured field (query)
'latest' - a list of blog posts, sorted by date (blog archives)
The featured post will have an image heavy design (while hiding things like post time/number of comments/tags/etc) while the latest posts will be a fairly traditional layout (showing the aforementioned fields). As such, these widgets, which are the same base type, need to have very different structures.

I have figured out how to access the individual widgets, the overall blog post and each of the individual parts of the blog posts, however I cannot figure out what level I should be creating a view at, to be able to style these individually.

At the content level, I have a reasonable amount of control (still reliant on the @Display(Model.Content) though) however, none of the alternates I can see in Shape Tracer will allow me to ONLY change the Content-BlogPost.cshtml (or similar) for the particular Widget or Zone (both would allow access).

What I really need is to be able to specify the zone AND the content area. (something like Zone-ZoneName-Content-BlogPost.cshtml)

Am I missing something important? or am I going about this completely wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards, 
Nick

(apologies for cross posting from codeplex, has been a few days and I really need to progress)

Comment: Did you enable widget alternates?

Comment: Hi Bertrand, thanks for the reply. 

Yeh, I have enabled widget alternates, and I can see the alternate for the widget itself inside the Shape tracing tool. 

My problem with this is that the 'Template' section (of the widget in shape tracer) only has the '@Display(Model.Content)'. Is it possible to get the entire template for the widget (eg. the detail you can see if you inspect the content or part shapes) so that I can modify the structure, but still maintain the same data?

Comment: Sure. You're not looking deep enough. Under content, there are local zones, and under those zones, there are the various shapes that the drivers created. It's usually those that you alternate.

Comment: Yeh, I have discovered the various parts/fields/etc. However, how can I reference those specific shapes within a content area but ALSO within a specific widget? If I change (for example) the 'Parts.Title.Summary-BlogPost.cshtml' template, it will modify both of the places I have blog posts on the page.

Comment: Well, that's where you need alternates. If you don't find the alternates you need on those shapes, you need to either create them, or add code in the template that distinguishes the context. Always prefer the first option. It can be implemented as a shape table provider.